# how to go about debugging "java.io.FileNotFoundException" (Too many open files in system)

Tags: java

I am completely new in terms of debugging java.io.FileNotFoundException (Too many open files in system) scenario.

When I run following command I see,

```
lsof |  grep tomcat | wc -l
62000
```

And our file max size is,

```
cat /fs/file-max
65000
```

So, java code started seeing below exceptions,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \/home\/tomcatsomething\/jobs\/logs\/some3011822301211797.log (Too many open files in system)"
```

I see all the JDBC connections in code are closed properly. where do I see where in code other file openings are happening?

Comment: For most operating systems, there is a finite number of File Handles that can be accessed. Once you cross that limit, you'll get the error. That means other programs or applications could have files open. Check those.

Comment: @oldercoder, good point. I am going to check on that.

Comment: Sockets are also file handles, so maybe you aren't closing connections (eg http connections to other webapps, database connections, etc).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I looked into database connections, they are being properly closed. Our app basically queries other databases and writes in log files. We started seeing FileNotFoundException because files opened by our app reaches almost the maximum allocated for our server. In the code, I see Files connections objects are closed properly. So, still investigating...